# Changing razor template deletes my session

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session, iis, razor

Hi I'm playing around with some sessions in my c# mvc application.
The trouble is if I change a razor template or compile my code it deletes all the session details.

What gives?
Compiling of code I kinda understand because it has to fire up the app pool and all that stuff but changing a layout. What's that about, can I change it?